# Determine the Maclaurin series expansion of $\frac{\mathrm{exp}(z)}{(z+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

Determine the Maclaurin series expansion of $\frac{\mathrm{exp}(z)}{(z+1)}$.

This is the composition of the series expansion of the exponential function centered about $z = -1$. We can rectify the expansion about $\mathrm{exp}(z)$ by writing:

$$\begin{aligned} 
\frac{\mathrm{exp}(z + 1)}{e (z+1)} &= \frac{1}{e(1+z)} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(z+1)^n}{n!} \\ 
&= \frac{1}{e} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(z+1)^{(n-1)}}{n!} 
\end{aligned}$$

Is this expansion correct? There is a slight uneasiness here that I have with calling this a Maclaurin expansion due to the centering and the negative power when $n = 0$.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you're right to be leery; 'Maclaurin' generally refers specifically to Taylor series centered around $z=0$, and Taylor itself implies no negative terms (otherwise it would be a Laurent series).

Comment: do you think it makes this expansion any less valid?

Comment: Instead, I would consider the Maclaurin series for $\exp(z)$ and for $\dfrac1{z+1}$ separately - both of which should be very easy to find - and then multiply them.

Comment: I think your expansion is _valid_, but I don't think it's the expansion that the question is looking for.

Comment: What you found is the Laurent expansion around $z = -1$.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the comment of *Steven Stadnicki*, the Maclaurin series is a taylor series centred at the origin so by the Cauchy product and since

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^k}{k!}\times(-z)^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\frac{z^n}{k!}=z^n\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}=c_nz^n$$
we find 
$$\frac{e^z}{z+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}\times\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-z)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nz^n$$

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I think now I have a correct answer. Isn't it?

Comment: Is $c_n$ intended to represent some well known sequence, or are you just defining $c_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane It looks essentially correct to me; I would've phrased it differently, but all the maths are correct.

Answer (score 0):

The function $e^z$ is entire and has Maclaurin series:

$$e^z=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!} + \cdots$$

The function $\frac{1}{1+z}$ has a pole at $z=-1$ and has a Maclaurin series which converges for $|z|<1$:

$$\frac{1}{1+z}=1-z+z^2-z^3+ \cdots$$

Their product has a series that converges for $|z|<1$:

$$\frac{e^z}{1+z} = 1+\frac{z^2}{2} -\frac{z^3}{3}+ \frac{3z^4}{8} -\frac{11z^5}{30}+ \frac{53z^6}{144} - \cdots$$

Comment: Note that the coefficient of $z^n$ for $n\geq 1$ can be written $( - 1)^n \left[ {\frac{{n!}}{e}} \right]\frac{1}{{n!}}$, where $\left[ x \right]$ denotes the nearest integer to $x$.

Comment: @Gary, that's an interesting result!  How did you arrive at that?

Comment: Look up derangements!

Comment: Will do! ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: It does not, because it gives exactly the same value as it does for $n=1$: $0$.

Comment: Oh right!  My mistake!  $1/e$ is closer to zero than to one.